# How to save a Slime Debugger buffer into a file, preserving all its data?

Tags: debugging, files, slime, save

I am using Common Lisp, SBCL, Emacs, and Slime. Often, an error will happen while programming.

When an error occurs, Slime opens a Debugger buffer. Sometimes, I would like to save this debugger buffer to a file so that other people could open and be able to read it. This is specially true when dealing with co-workers.

Thus, I do in Emacs:

1 - `M-x write-file`;

2 - Choose a path;

3 - Create a file defining its file extension.

I tried saving a `.txt` and a `.lisp` files. But after opening it is not the same.

For instance, I wish the interaction from things like `---more---` would still be preserved if someone opens this in another Emacs.

Is there a smarter way to share this data to a different Emacs?

Comment: This isn't on topic, but I'm wondering if it would make more sense to let others connect via ssh to a given CL program to recreate a given state and thus debug it.

Comment: For deterministically reproducible errors, a saved image might get you there: http://www.lichteblau.com/sbcl/doc/manual/sbcl/Saving-a-Core-Image.html -- it unwinds the stack, unfortunately, so it can't give you complete immediate reproducibility.